# Why does giving a format specifier of float to assigned integer results as 0.000000?

Tags: c, printf, output

I tried to give format specifier of float to an assigned integer and it results in 0 and also if  in the same statement another float b given an format specifier of integer it gives absurd output and in the function `surp` if I try to assign the right format specifier to b it results in 0. Is this wrong format specifier that is assigned initially disturbing the whole statement?

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main()
{
    int i;
    float b;
    i=5;
    b=3.5;
    printf("%f and %d\n",i,b);
    surp();

}

int surp()
{
    int i;
    float b;
    i=5;
    b=3.5;
    printf("%f and %f\n",i,b);
}
```

It outputs:

```
0.000000 and 1074528256  
0.000000 and 0.000000
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because 'I did an obviusly stupid thing and got stupid results, but I want it explained'.   There ought to be some sort of tag for this kind of question, (other than 'useless to future users/visitors').

Answer (score 2):

This code invokes undefined behaviour in both calls to `printf`, as you appear yourself to be aware. Anything can happen, including the output that you observe.

```
printf("%f and %d\n",i,b); // both i and b do not match
printf("%f and %f\n",i,b); // i does not match
```

You must provide values that match the format specifiers used. It's pointless trying to reason about the undefined behaviour that follows when you don't do this.

Your `main` function should be `int main(void)`. And the `surp` function is called before it is declared, and in the implementation is missing a `return` statement.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you're expecting sensible results when you're provoking undefined behaviour.

In both cases you are using float specifying and putting in an integer.

The thing is that those variables potentially have different sizes, and the functions needs to consume and interpret it appropriately. You might be very well provoking memory violations.

Btw if you are using gcc you can use `-Wformat` switch so the compiler will analyze the syntax and type for you and give a warning.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to print an integer as float is undefined behaviour. Anything from a program crash to what output you are getting can happen. That makes it meaningless to discuss.

btw:

```
b=3.5;
```

Is still probably not what you want.

`3.5` by default is interpreted as a `double` literal, which means it will be implicitly cast to a `float` in this , leading to additional rounding.

do

```
b = 3.5f;
```

instead